# Weekly Average In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large year-long dataframe of occurrences with month (1-12), week (1-52), day_of_week (0-6), and hour (0-23).

Below is just a snippet of the dataset.  Each row is an occurrence.

The first part of the snippet below shows multiple occurrences captured with a date/timestamp of 2018-04-01 00:00:00 (Sunday).  The second part of the snippet below (after the first ellipses) shows multiple occurrences in the following hour and the third part is the next hour, and so on.

```
    month week  day_of_week  hour
0     4    13        6         0
1     4    13        6         0
2     4    13        6         0
3     4    13        6         0
4     4    13        6         0
...
100   4    13        6         1
101   4    13        6         1
102   4    13        6         1
...
...
300   4    13        6         2
301   4    13        6         2
302   4    13        6         2
...
```

I would like to be able to display a summary of this dataset showing the weekly average count of occurrences for each of the hours (0-23) as well as for each month.

For example:

```
month  hour  weekly_ave
4        0       100
4        1       175
4        2       250
...
4       23       500
5        0        90
```

How do I do this using pandas groupby and aggregate functions?

Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby(['month','week'])['hour'].mean()` ? have you read the groupby docs ? they are fairy simple

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice but not quite what I was looking for.  I wanted to see how each hour is trending through the weeks in every month. Yes, I have read the pandas groupby docs and they are indeed fairly simple but not for what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I had to do a second `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['month', 'hour', 'week']) \
    .agg({'day_of_week': 'count'}) \
    .groupby(['month', 'hour']).mean() \
    .rename(columns={"day_of_week": "weekly_ave"}).reset_index()
```

This gave me what I needed but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['month','hour'])['hour'].count()
```

Then, if you need this formatted a little bit nicer:

```
df.groupby(['month','hour'])['hour'].count().rename("weekly:ave").reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom but I was getting the sum of the weeks and not the mean.

Comment: @DennisLabajo No problem, hadn't realised that you wanted to count `day_of_week` also.